# Is there a concept of virtual/logical project aggregation?

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to have a subproject with no associated folder in sbt?

I have a few subprojects and I'd like to aggregate them in different ways without sbt creating empty folders for me on the fly.

For example, if I have the following build definition:

```
lazy val a, b, c, d = project
```

for subprojects `a` to `d`, I'd like to make a "virtual aggregate" `abd` that would aggregate `a`, `b` and `d`, with another called `acd` for `a`, `c`, and `d`, and obviously the default root project would aggregate all of them.

I can do that right now as follows:

```
val a = project
val b = project
val c = project
val d = project

val abd = project.aggregate(a, b, d)
val acd = project.aggregate(a, c, d)

// root implicitly aggregates all of them
```

The problem is that sbt creates a folder for each project, even for the virtual aggregates, making it a less appealing option.

Is there a way to set up sbt so `abd` and `acd` exist only for organizational purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to have a virtual project, but I'm quite sure that that's not what you really want.

[Aggregation means that running a task on the aggregate project will also run it on the aggregated projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation) so I can only suspect you want to have such virtual projects to execute tasks across projects.

If so, you need some help from [ScopeFilter](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/ScopeFilter.scala) that creates project ranges similar to aggregation in which you can read values of tasks (*aka* task execution) or settings (*aka* setting assignment).

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val a, b, c, d = project

val abd = ScopeFilter(inProjects(a, b, d), inConfigurations(Compile))

val acd = ScopeFilter(inProjects(a, c, d), inConfigurations(Compile))
```

ScopeFilter is described in the official documentation of sbt in [Getting values from multiple scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Getting+values+from+multiple+scopes).

Without much details, it's hard to give you some further help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we do in activator/sbt-server (mostly for manual cross versioning semantics) is add source directories together.

You can see an example here:  https://github.com/sbt/sbt-remote-control/blob/master/project/build.scala#L34

However, if you're looking for compilation separation as well, you may want to look into using something like sbt-assembly to aggregate your projects into one "uber jar" after the fact, and have downstream dependencies use this "fat" dependency.